# How to get XCode to see private keys for signing certificates?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, keychain, private-key

I'm using Mojave 10.14.6 and XCode 11.0.
I've been using this OS and XCode version for more than 1 year without problem. Now, suddenly, when I go to upload my app to the App Store with Automatic Signing, XCode no longer finds the private key for the signing certificates. This is odd, since I can see the private key in Keychain Access, so I know it is there.

[Image of Missing Private Key error from XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqhi8.png)

[Image showing that my signing certificates/private keys aren't being found in keychain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr69w.png)

This is infuriating.  I have deleted all of my certificates, and then let XCode regenerate them. I've downloaded the *.p12 files and then moved them into Keychain. But XCode still won't recognize them.  I work alone, so "contacting the certificate owner for the private key" makes no sense. I simply need Xcode and my computer to communicate.

I have also gone to my IOS developer account, deleted certificates there, and re-created the certificates online, downloaded the *.p12 file to Keychain. But still Xcode won't use the file and apparently can't see the private key.

Is there a way to force-feed a private key to XCode? Any ideas why XCode cannot see the keys on my computer?

I'm unable to post any updates to my app.  I've been trying solutions to this problem for days without success. Please help!

Comment: I manage to get this to work by Manual Signing.  I also found that my profiles were out of date, even if my certificates were valid.  HOWEVER, I've just learned that I need to update my XCode for SDK 14.0, which also means updating my OS. But this is at least a better problem to have.